# How to model more that one product in a classic star schema?

Tags: modeling

I am building a classic star schema in a data warehouse for reporting.

My measure is Data(MB) per phone number per month.

My dimensions are Time, Product, Customer and Supplier.

My problem is that some customers have bought more than one product per phone number in some month.

Any ideas on how to implement this in a classic star schema?

Adding these columns to my fact table?

- PRODUCT_1_FK
- PRODUCT_2_FK
- PRODUCT_3_FK

Regards,

Christian

Comment: You should strictly distinct between *product subscription* and *product usage*. The former is more or less trivial and there is not a problem with multiple products as you are on a *customer level*. The latter is more involved; a typical workaround is to choose some *main* product and add it in the fact table or if this is not feasible simple ommit it and let the *queriees* to make their own picture by combining the *usage* and *subscription* tables. Basically you need to *replicate* the billing process logic, where typically for each *usage* only one product is choosen for the *rating*.

Comment: How do you calculate the Data(MB) measure?

Comment: Imagine that a customer bought 20 products per month ? It's obvious that you don't have a fix number of columns you need then to denormalize it by having a seperate record in your fact table for each transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine this scenario :

- Customer with ID =101 bought the product with ID=100 by phone , on
  25 Jan 2021
- The same Customer with ID=101 bought another product with ID=120 by
  phone, on 28 Jan 2021

How would be in your Fact table?

```
CustomerSK ProductSK SupplierSK TimeSK
101        100       122        25-01-2021 09:00:30
101        120       189        28-01-2021 16:08:11
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your measure is "Data(MB) per phone number per month" then you can't include Product as a dimension as that would alter the grain of your measure.

If you want to the grain of your measure to be "Data(MB) per product per phone number per month" then you'd need to add Product to your fact and you would have 1 fact record per product